# git push.default setting after installing xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, git

I don't know for sure that this was caused by my xcode installation, but that's the only major change that happened on my computer before git stopped working. I also found some info on github that suggested this might be the problem. Anyway, whenever I try to pull, clone, or push, I get this message:

```
error: Malformed value for push.default: simple
error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current.
fatal: bad config file line 3 in /Users/mbc/.gitconfig
```

If I run `git --version`, I get this: git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)

I tried installing the latest version, but even though the installer claimed success, `git --version` has not changed.

So maybe git is installed in two different places? `which git` gives me `/usr/bin/git` but I'm not sure where git is supposed to be, so this is not particularly helpful yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install git? Standalone installer, some package manager? My git is in `usr/local/bin/git`, the Apple-supplied git at the same place as yours. You probably should change the PATH variable accordingly.

Comment: It was with the standalone installer

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour can indeed be explained by the installation of Xcode. In fact, I had very similar behaviour by upgrading to Mavericks, because that apparently reinstalls or updates Xcode.

What happened is this : you had a fully working version of git installed, which you had configured to use `simple` for its `push.default`. Xcode gets installed (or updated), and brings with it another, outdated version of git, which does not yet know of the option `simple` for `push.default`. When you type `git` on the command line, your `PATH` is searched for a binary to execute. The Xcode-git is found on your path first, before your more recent version of git. Installing git again doesn't help, because it is still installed in the same location, and that location is on your path after the Xcode git.

One possible solution, as already suggested by silent1mezzo, is to do this in terminal :

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git
sudo ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

However, if you then upgrade Xcode and it reinstalls its own git again, it will overwrite that link we just created. This is probably what caused it to break on my upgrade to Mavericks.

Another option is to put /usr/local/git/bin in your path *before* /usr/bin. You could do this by putting a line like this in your .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

(if you don't have a file .bash_profile yet, just create it in your home directory)

This will cause the more recent version of git to be the one that is found first when your path is searched. One detail : terminals that are already open when you put that line in .bash_profile won't get the new behaviour right away - you could run `source ~/.bash_profile` to get them to the new behaviour, or just close them and start them again.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at **/Users/mbc/.gitconfig** line 3 and see what value is actually there.

*[edit...]*

If you are trying to track what is on GitHub, I would try changing the value to 'tracking' and see if that fixes your problem. The error message would indicate that the current value of 'simple' is completely wrong.

Comment: there is no line 3. this is the contents of the file:
[push]
        default = simple

Answer (score 0):

`default = simple` was introduced in git 1.7.11, so your version of git doesn't recognize it:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/200276

Some options for you:

- Install a newer version of git (I like homebrew to handle these things, and it's currently got git 1.8.1.1 available, but go with what makes you comfortable)
- Use an alternative configuration, as the error message suggests. (See above link for some options--I don't know which value would be best for your situation.)
- If you've already installed another version of git, but it's not showing up, make sure /usr/local/bin is in front of /usr/bin in your path.

The third option solved this problem for me.  My editor wasn't configured to respect my user's custom path, so it was defaulting to the Apple-installed git instead of the homebrew package.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem by typing the two following lines into the terminal

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git
sudo ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Basically XCode command line tools installed it's version of git to /usr/bin/git and when I installed Git from their website it installed it to `/usr/local/git`.

By deleting the first version and sym-linking the downloaded version everything worked correctly.